# Heruko Deployment Cannot read property location of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a react application. I have made the use of a  third party library called unlayer editor. https://unlayer.com/
It works perfectly on development mode but when I have pushed it to heroku, it gives the following error

```
editor.js:formatted:9428 TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
    at Function.mapToProps (editor.js:formatted:43314)
    at r (editor.js:formatted:12784)
    at Function.r.mapToProps (editor.js:formatted:12790)
    at r (editor.js:formatted:12784)
    at editor.js:formatted:13038
    at Object.run (editor.js:formatted:11949)
    at o.initSelector (editor.js:formatted:11961)
    at new o (editor.js:formatted:11888)
    at constructClassInstance (editor.js:formatted:8912)
    at beginWork (editor.js:formatted:9021)
```

Is it the problem with the library or the environment where it is run?